# How do I add acronyms that appear in a figure/image to the acronyms list at the front of my document?

Tags: acronyms

I'm using Texmaker and I've created a list of acronyms for my `article` document. I've used this type of code in the preamble to generate the acronyms list:

```
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{a}{A}{Apple}
```

Then within the text itself, I have used:

```
\gls{a}
```

to get the acronym to appear in the text, all within the same `.tex` file. This works very well, without any problems, when I'm looking to add the acronyms to the list that are in-text, as they appear in the list whenever I use the `\gls{}` command.

My issue is with adding acronyms to the list when I don't use them in the text. For example, I have some that appear in figures/images that I've added into the document but I cannot get to appear in the acronyms list. All the ones I want to use, even the ones in images, are already written into the code using:

```
\newacronym{a}{A}{Apple}
```

How do I get acronyms to appear in the acronyms list that appear in images and not in-text?

Answer (score 2):

You write `\glsadd{word}` to add `word` to the acronyms list without having `word` in your text. Or `\gsaddall` to get all the defined ones in the list. Or `\glsaddallunused` to add all the unused ones (the difference between these can be important if page numbers are added to the list).

Comment: I went with the '\glsaddallunused' one in the end, since I already had a number of them defined and it worked really well. Thanks very much!